# How do I store data inside a promise in an array(JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-promise

the code below doesn't add anything to the array after being done. I thought by including another then would resolve the data and allow me to use it outside of the scope.

```js
function getImgUrls(searchItems) {
  searchItems.forEach(currentItem => {
    let image;
    imgClient.search(currentItem, options).
    then(images => {
      return images[0].url;
    }).then(finalResult => {
      console.log(finalResult);
      pushToArray(finalResult);  
    })
    .catch(error => {console.log(error); });
  });
}
```

Comment: you have some undefined variables in there. it would help if you could explain what is the searchItems input and what is the imgClient object and its search function and where those variables are coming from.

Comment: Another note that might be your problem is that the finalResult is there as a parameter so using pushToArray wont do much because the array is not maintained outside the scope of the function.

Comment: I actually declared the array outside of the function. I just didn't include it in the snippet.

Comment: It's unclear what you understand as "*resolve the data*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a whole bunch of promises so you will need to know when they are all done.  The simplest way here is to use `Promise.all()`.  And, since you're trying to accumulate an array of promises, it's best to use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`:

```
function getImgUrls(searchItems) {
    return Promise.all(searchItems.map(currentItem => {
        return imgClient.search(currentItem, options).then(images => {
            //  make the url be the resolved value of the promise
            return images[0].url; 
        });
    }));
}

getImgUrls(...).then(urls => {
    console.log(urls);    // final array of urls
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: so for this to work, would i have to include two different function calls from where I am executing the code? would i have to call "getImgUrls(parameter);" twice or just once like i am currently doing?

Comment: @Konedi -  You just call it once, pass it the `searchItems` array and it returns a promise that resolves to an array of URLs.  I don't understand why you'd think you have to call it twice.  You can NEVER reliably use the result outside the scope of the `.then()` handler.  That's how asynchronous operations work in Javascript and how you program with them.  You use the result INSIDE the `.then()` handler or call a function from the `.then()` handler and pass the result to that function.

Comment: sorry I am new to promises. I just don't get how the second "getImgUrls(...).then" is going to be executed. plus I just found out that it gives me an error. like invalid syntax.

Comment: @Konedi - I don't know what you mean about "second getImgUrls()".  There's nothing in your question about that.  And, as always here, we can't help you fix errors in the code you're trying without seeing the exact code you're trying and knowing what the exact error message is.  You could "edit" your question and add your new issue to the end of your question (don't change the first part of the question).  Also, it's a little hard to do this if the turn-around time is 21 hours.

Comment: yeah sorry about that. The issue is actually solved now thanks. Just that another issue came up but that's beyond the scope of this question.thanks.